# How to target label element based on input element's dynamic class?

Tags: css, html, forms, selector

HTML

```
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email"></input>
```

The `class` attribute of the email `input` element may change, like if the user enters an invalid email format. I only want that `label` to change to red when the `input` it's for gets the class "invalid".

In fact, I want ALL my labels with a `for` attribute to be "invalid aware" of their assigned `input` elements.

CSS Attempt:

```
label[for=*.invalid]{
     color: red;
}
```

The above is probably incorrect because I might have to specify a specific form element by name.

Comment: No. I said label whose "for" element, and that element has a particular class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 1

If you're adding a dynamic class to the `input` element (`.invalid`), why not add a class to the `label` element, as well? This would simplify the styling of the label when the input fails validation.

#### Option 2

I understand that changing the label color to red highlights an error to the user. In this option you still highlight an error to the user, but in a slightly different way. The CSS [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) and [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) pseudo-classes represent `form` and `input` elements that validate or fail to validate. These pseudo-classes style the `input` not the `label`.

#### Option 3

This option involves the sibling and attribute selectors. You would have to reverse the order of your `label` and `input` in the HTML (but this doesn't have to change the appearance on the screen; see below).

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="invalid"></input>
<label for="email">Email</label>
```

CSS

```
input[class="invalid"] + label { color: red; }
```

**Changing the visual order of elements with CSS Flexbox**

Despite the order of elements in the DOM, you can still change the *visual order* of elements with [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes). So if you didn't want to put the `label` after the `input` for the sake of appearance there's an easy workaround: Wrap the `input` and `label` in a flexbox and use the [`order` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to arrange their display order.

---

*A few side notes...*

- HTML5 provides an [`input`  `type="email"‌`​](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input), which you may want to consider instead of `type="text"`. One benefit being that when mobile devices see `type="email"` they often launch an e-mail-friendly keyboard.
- Second, the `input` element is a [void element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements). No closing tag required. You can safely remove the `</input>`.
- Lastly, the `for` attribute associates a `label` element with a matching `ID`. In your code, you would need to add `id="email"` to your `input` for the label click feature to work.

Comment: That was what I was avoiding, and also JavaScript - no JavaScript, please. Yup, I'm lazy, but I might just settle for it.

Comment: I'm working in Angular, so Option 1 is really easy so I'll go for that. Thank you for the options.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` attribute has to match the `id` (not the `name`, not the `class`) of the associated input.

In order to change the `label` based on a feature of the `input` you need to either:

- Use combinators to draw a connection between the two elements (which is impossible when the `label` precedes the `input`) *or*
- Use JavaScript to modify the `label` (e.g. by adding a class).

Comment: I want to be less specific than having to specify an id for each label. Otherwise, I would have to write the same exact CSS rule (if there is) for each label-input pair.

Comment: You can write a CSS rule that matches all your label/input pairs by using a class (or even type) selector. You need to make the for match the id in order to associate the label with the input so that it will be connected to the input for the benefit of people who click on the label or use a screen reader.